# How to zip CSV file ? Azure Data Lake / Databricks

Tags: zip, databricks, azure-data-lake

I have a CSV file in Azure Data Lake.
I'd like to change type for this file to csv.gz by DataBricks.

I can write this file to df, then save file as csv.gz and then remove csv file from data lake.

Is it possible to change type to csv.gz without writing file to df?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to change type to csv.gz without writing file to df?

No, it is not possible. Write this file to df, then save file as csv.gz and then remove csv file from data lake is the right way.